# Implementation of a counter of comparisons for the quickSort algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a counter of comparisons for the quickSort algorithm in javascript.

I have tested my code agains't some base cases, and my result is always very close to the correct one (22 instead of 25 for this test). I can't figure out what's wrong with my code, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
let comparisons = 0;


    function quick_Sort(origArray) {
        if (origArray.length <= 1) { 
            return origArray;
        } else {

            var left = [];
            var right = [];
            var newArray = [];
            var pivot = origArray.shift();
            var length = origArray.length;
            // I have tried comparisons += length - 1; too, but i doesn't work
            comparisons += length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (origArray[i] <= pivot) {
                    left.push(origArray[i]);
                    
                } else {
                    right.push(origArray[i]);
                }
            }
    
            return newArray.concat(quick_Sort(left), pivot, quick_Sort(right));
        }
    }

quick_Sort([2148, 9058, 7742, 3153, 6324, 609, 7628, 5469, 7017, 504]); 
// expected output: 25

console.log(comparisons);
```

Comment: Hey, please provide the data you're testing this with and only the `quick_Sort` function so that your snippet is actually runnable. (Also, `comparaisons` is not defined.)

Comment: how you know `25` is the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change `comparaisons += length - 1;` with `comparaisons += length;`. The number of comparisons are equal to the number of iterations of the `for` loop.

This is a trace of the complete process with the sample array that you have provided, showing the number of comparisons, the pivot, left and right parts of each recursion step. The number of comparisons is not 25, it is equal to 29:

```
[ 2148, 9058, 7742, 3153, 6324, 609, 7628, 5469, 7017, 504 ] (Comparisons: 9)
- Pivot: 2148
- Left: [ 609, 504 ] (Comparisons 1)
- Right: [ 9058, 7742, 3153, 6324, 7628, 5469, 7017 ] (Comparisons: 6)
  - Pivot: 9058
  - Left: [ 7742, 3153, 6324, 7628, 5469, 7017 ] (Comparisons: 5)
    - Pivot: 7742
    - Left: [ 3153, 6324, 7628, 5469, 7017 ] (Comparisons: 4)
      - Pivot: 3153
      - Left: [ ]
      - Right: [ 6324, 7628, 5469, 7017 ] (Comparisons: 3)
        - Pivot: 6354
        - Left: [ 5469 ]
        - Right: [ 7628, 7017 ] (Comparisons: 1)
    - Right: [ ]
  - Right: [ ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i passed a lot of time trying to understand why i was not able to get 25 as a result (there is apparently an error in my assignment).